# Is it possible to write Bengali with pdfLaTex compiler in the Overleaf platform?

Tags: xetex, pdftex, overleaf

Is it possible to write **Bengali** with a **pdfLaTex** compiler in the **Overleaf** platform? I can easily write Bengali using XeLaTex or LuaLatex but I want to write with pdfLaTex. There are two main reasons behind this,

1. If I write any scientific paper using XeLaTex or LuaLatex its preprint could not be submitted in arXiv because they accept only pdfLaTex. You can find the details [here](https://arxiv.org/help/submit_tex).
2. According to many journal requirements, you have to submit the latex file but unfortunately, they did not support XeLaTex or LuaLatex.

So, I think it will be very helpful for me If I can prepare my manuscript using pdfLaTex in overleaf.

I have tried using babel in overleaf but it did not show any Bangla font.

[image]

Comment: well there are some old packages to support bengali, e.g. https://ctan.org/pkg/bangtex. I have no idea how well they worked.  But I would in your place complain very loudly about the discrimination of your script. Unicode support should be normal today.

Comment: It’s possible to trick arXiv into accepting a PDF made with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX by removing the metadata. But—although I appreciate the service they provide and am sure there is a reason for it that makes sense from their perspective—if they upgraded their software, a lot of people could start writing their new papers in modern TeX. Then we’d get a lot fewer questions saying they have to use PDFTeX and a lot fewer accepted answers that only work for it.

Comment: it may be possible to get some very basic rendering but pdflatex really has no support for the kind of font shaping you need for these scripts. It can not use the truetype or open type fonts. You should use xelatex (it is possible to submit to arxiv)

Comment: How can I submit my xelatex compiled in arxiv?

Answer (score 0):

I specifically needed a solution that could be **compiled with pdflatex on Overleaf**. As you mentioned, unfortunately, many of the modern packages require XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

For this, you can use [pdflatex_bengali](https://github.com/aritraghsh09/pdflatex_bengali) based on the [bangtex](http://www.saha.ac.in/theory/palashbaran.pal/bangtex/bangtex.html) package.

#### Quickstart Guide

- Put the [mf](https://github.com/aritraghsh09/bangtex_overleaf/tree/main/mf) folder along with all its contents in the same directory as your LaTeX source code.
- Put the [bangla_commands.tex](https://github.com/aritraghsh09/bangtex_overleaf/blob/main/bangla_commands.tex) file in the same directory as your LaTeX source code.
- Put `\input{bangla_commands}` in the preamble of your LaTeX source code
- When you write বাংলা enclose it within the `\bng` command like this `{\bng baNNGla \*l*ikhun}` which should output বাংলা লিখুন
- The `\bng` command can be replaced by commands specifying other sizes, and this is outlined in the
  [demo.tex](https://github.com/aritraghsh09/bangtex_overleaf/blob/main/demo.tex) and
  [demo.pdf](https://github.com/aritraghsh09/bangtex_overleaf/blob/main/demo.pdf) files.
- A simple example document is shown below

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\title{Bengali Test}
\author{{\lbng Airt/r \*gh*eaSh}}

\input{bangla_commands}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Example}

{\bng baNNGla \*l*ikhun}

\end{document}
```